# IE8 Stopped Keeping History

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, history

Like the title says, apparently my IE8 has stopped keeping the history of pages I've visited. I've searched SU and Google and can't find anything that seems to describe what I'm seeing. I have IE set to retain history for 999 days (the maximum allowed):

[image: Settings]

As you can see below, apart from today and last Thursday, IE appears to be oblivious to any activity more recent than three weeks ago. Clicking on either "Thursday" or "Today" reveals no recorded history, however. Very odd behavior. Finally, the history *does* extend back 30 weeks to when I built the computer, and there *is* recorded history for every week. I'd appreciate suggestions.

NB. Windows 7 Ultimate, x64 (but 32-bit IE8).

[image: History Pane]

Comment: Does internet explorer without addons work? (run IE with the no addons option). How about just resetting ie8 settings?

Comment: This is why I use Chrome

Comment: @KronoS: Chrome + Google = Privacy Issues. That is why I use Firefox.

Comment: Too true, especially since they are trying to take over the world with verizon.

Comment: I regularly use Chrome because it loads so blazingly fast. I use FF only when I need FireBug (it loads so slowly, I can usually go for coffee). Unfortunately, it seems that every time I try to abandon IE, it takes no time at all for me to find a web site that won't work on any other browser. I also use Opera and Safari. But then that's all part of "Browser Wars" and not a conversation for here.

Comment: @BillP3rd: FF slow load can easily be fixed by MinimizeToTray Revived: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12581/

Comment: I couldn't resist... Related: http://www.businesspundit.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/cookiemonster.jpg

Comment: Try to reset IE and check again.
If the issue still persists, troubleshoot in Clean Boot Mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Try an IE Reset**

[image]

If you're not concerned with losing history and just concerned with fixing it, I'd try an IE Reset. Works pretty well at getting IE back to normal when it starts acting up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that might cause this (or might manifest like this), but I can think of nothing definitive.

Firstly, I would try increasing the disk space allowed for pages to perhaps 220 MB from the current 200 and see if it then starts saving web pages. If that's the case, then you'll probably want to re-evaluate needing to store history for just under three years, or be willing to appropriate more disk space for it. I wouldn't have thought IE8 would classify 'history' as coming under 'cached webpages' though, so this might not help.

Secondly, do you run any cleanup or optimisation programs like CCleaner? I would expect these to clear the *whole* history rather than a recent section, though.

Thirdly, as Nano8Blazex suggests, there could be a clash with IE8 addons. Could you kindly click on "Tools" and then "Manage add-ons" and let us know what addons you have installed? The list might be surprisingly long, so thanks in advance ;)

Comment: 1/ I've increased space from the default 200 to 1023 MB. 2/ I don't use programs like CCleaner. 3/ I've disabled all IE addons. No change.

Answer (score 0):

In thread [IE8 does not store History or Temp Internet Files](http://www.techimo.com/forum/technical-support/229162-ie8-does-not-store-history-temp-internet-files.html) it is claimed:

> IE8 in windows 7 does not store temp
>   internet files till you disable the
>   protected mode under security ( IE -
>   tools - internet options - Security )

So turning off protected mode is worth trying.

Another thread, [Why would IE8 on Vista not keep any history when browsing in normal mode?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaie/thread/3012806a-9851-488e-a1a8-d6101a1a5d49), suggests closing IE, going to Control Panel -> Folder Options, on the View tab enable "Show hidden files" and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files", then in directory `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows` delete the hidden system folder called "History". All history is this way reinitialized to empty, so it might take some time to verify if it works correctly now.

Comment: Protected mode isn't related to this problem (http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/58608.aspx). Deleting everything in the History folder hadn't occurred to me (and seems a bit extreme) but I'll definitely keep it in mind as a last resort.

Comment: @BillP3rd: (1) It doesn't hurt to try turning off protected mode. Some people with IE8 history problems reported that this fixed them. (2) If you rename History, then it's not lost.

Comment: I tried turning off protected mode. No history but IE *did* warn me on *every* page I visited that protected mode was disabled. Of course, if I decide to try wiping history, I'd make sure I had a copy, but I appreciate the warning. :-)

Comment: @BillP3rd: IE is not supposed to warn on every page, only once. Something might be screwed up. Maybe you should use Internet Options > Advanced Tab > Reset Button.